# jQuery mobile page height UNWANTEDLY increases each time page is loaded

Tags: jquery, html, jquery-mobile

I do not really have a lot of information to go off here, so if its too open ended I apologise.

Basically I am making a jQuery mobile app, and each time I open a page (AJAX, not external), the height of the page div increases by 134px.

I noticed by trying to set the height of two containing divs to 50% height of the page on load. I noticed the two divs were getting bigger and bigger each time the page wass loaded:

```js
var h = $('#storeLocatorMapDisplay').height(); 
$("#map_canvas").css("height", .5*h);
$("#mapLegend").css("height", .5*h);
alert(h);
```

So anyway, I decided to set the height of the two divs by pixels, but the "h" height still increases by 134px each time I visit the page.

Hope im not missing something obvious here??? :/

Thanks

Comment: you're storing the height and then multiply it by .5